# jqgrid addRowData gives error t.p.data.push is not a function

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am adding data to the grid using a custom button. In case if data already exists in the grid, the new row is added correctly. But if the grid is empty and i add new row, it gives Uncaught TypeError: t.p.data.push is not a function error at jqgrid source file. Code used to add a new row is as below

```
var rows = $("#" + gridName).getDataIDs();
$("#" + gridName).jqGrid("addRowData", rows.length + 1, {
Id: rows.length + 1},'first');
$("#" + gridName).editRow(rows.length + 1, true);
```

I am using a custom nav bar for adding and editing the grid.

The grid is created using the following code
 createJqGrid:function(gridId, columns, gridData){

```
        $("#"+gridId).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: gridData,
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            colModel: columns,
            loadonce: false,
            //width: '100%',
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit:false,
            height: 250,
            rownumbers: false,
            multiselect: true,
            cellEdit: true,
            toppager: true,
            cloneToTop: true,
            rowNum: 10000,
            pager: "#pager"+gridId,
            cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
            ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol) {
                //$("#save" + gridId).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
            },
            beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
                return true;
            },
            beforeCellSelect: function(rowid, e) {
                return true;
            },
            afterEditCell: function(rowid, cellName, cellValue, iRow, iCol) {

                var cellDOM = this.rows[iRow].cells[iCol];
                $(cellDOM).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
                $("#save" + gridId).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");

            },
            onCellSelect: function(rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                //$("#save" + gridId).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
             return true;
            },
            loadComplete: function() {

            }

        });

$("#"+gridId).navGrid("#pager"+gridId, {
            cloneToTop: true,
            edit: false,
            search: false,
            add: false,
            del: false,
            refresh: false,
            view: false
        });
```

After the grid is created, based on some calls, I update the gridData for the grid.

Toolbar is added using

```
        grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + grid[0].id + '_toppager_left', { // "#list_toppager_left"
            caption: "",
            title: "Add",
            id: 'add' + gridName,
            onClickButton: function() {
                // perform something...
                var rows = $("#" + gridName).getDataIDs();
                $("#" + gridName).jqGrid("addRowData", rows.length + 1, {
                    Id: rows.length + 1
                },'first');

                $("#" + gridName).editRow(rows.length + 1, true);

                // Call this whenever Save button needs to be Enabled
                $("#save" + gridName).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
            }
        });
```

when the grid has some data, addRowData works, but when the grid is empty, it gives the error

```
                if(t.p.datatype === 'local') {
                    lcdata[t.p.localReader.id] = id;
                    t.p._index[id] = t.p.data.length;
                    t.p.data.push(lcdata); // Error comes on this line
                    lcdata = {};
                }
```

Comment: Fire of all you should **always** write which version of jqGrid you use and which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old version of jqGrid in version <= 4.7). The problem in one version can not exist in another version. Moreover you assign `data` using `gridData`. Which value have `gridData` "when the grid is empty"? It should be empty array `[]` and not `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Moreover the filling of grid using `var rows = $("#" + gridName).getDataIDs();$("#" + gridName).jqGrid("addRowData", rows.length + 1, {..},'first');...` is bad especially if you do this in the loop and fill the grid with many rows. In any way the usage of `rows.length + 1` is bad choice if the rows can be deleted and not only inserted. I recommend you to use `$.jgrid.randId()` function instead which could **generate unique value which van be used as rowid**.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. The error was that the data was not an empty array.  Fixing that corrected the issue. I have also fixed the code and I am not using randId instead of rows.length.

Comment: If you move your comment to an answer, i'll accept it as a solution for my question

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. I posted short answer with the same information, which I posted before as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign `data` using `gridData`. Which value have `gridData` "when the grid is empty"? It should be empty array [] and not `undefined` or `null`.

Moreover the filling of grid using `var rows = $("#" + gridName).getDataIDs();$("#" + gridName).jqGrid("addRowData", rows.length + 1, {..},'first');...` is bad especially if you do this in the loop and fill the grid with many rows. In any way the usage of `rows.length + 1` is bad choice if the rows *can be deleted* and not only inserted. I recommend you to use `$.jgrid.randId()` function instead which could generate unique value which van be used as rowid.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue

Error was 
I was adding data in object format for example array and not in local string 
So the data type of grid should be Json and not local

This will clear your error

Thank you :)