# jqgrid addRowData gives error "v.p.data.push is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to create two tables through Jqgrid
and add data to another table when I click the row of one table.

Click to move the data to another table, but an error similar to "v.p.data.push is not a function" occurs.
I think it's a matter of the type of data.
I think it's a problem because it's object-type data that "getRowData", but I don't know why the error occurs.

Please give me some advice.

It's my first time writing stackoverflow, so I'm lacking in writing like this. Please excuse me.

Table to click on

```
        var gridFormat_1={
                    data : '',
                datatype : 'local',
                // mtype : 'POST',
                loadonce : true,
             viewrecords : true,
                   width : 600,                 
                  height : 500,                  
                  rowNum : 50,                   
                 rowList : [50,100,500],     
              rownumbers : false,                
             rownumWidth : 25,                  
                sortname : 'emp_no',            
               sortorder : 'asc',                
             multiselect : false,                
                sortable : false,         
               autowidth : true,                 
                 iScroll : {zoom:true},       
                   pager : '#jqGridPager_1',
                 caption : ' ',
              whitespace : 'nowrap', 
               wordbreak : true,
                 // autoRow : true,
              //colNames :['emp_no','emp_nm', 'pst_nm', 'dept_nm','dept_cd','pst_cd'],
           colModel :[
                                       {label: 'emp_no',            name:'emp_no',          index:'emp_no',         sortable:'text', sorttype:'text',         width:50, align:'left',   editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'emp_nm',          name:'emp_nm',            index:'emp_nm',         sorttype:'text', sorttype:'text',         width:60, align:'left',   editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'pst_nm',            name:'pst_nm',          index:'pst_nm',         sorttype:'text', sorttype:'text',         width:60, align:'center', editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'dept_nm',           name:'dept_nm',         index:'dept_nm',        sorttype:'text', sorttype:'text',         width:60, align:'center', editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'dept_cd',       name:'dept_cd',         index:'dept_cd',        sortable:'text', sorttype:'text',        width:130, align:'left',   editable:false , height:'auto',  hidden:true }, 
                                       {label: 'pst_cd',        name:'pst_cd',          index:'pst_cd',         sorttype:'text', sorttype:'text',        width:60, align:'left',   editable:false , height:'auto',  hidden:true }, 
                                       
                                ],    
            loadError : function(xhr, status, err){ 
                try {
                    jQuery.jgrid.info_dialog(
                        jQuery.jgrid.errors.errcap,''
                        + xhr.responseText + '', jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose,
                        {buttonalign:'right'}
                    );
                } catch(e) { 
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                } 
            }
        };
         
        $.init_grid_table($("#main_table_1"),gridFormat_1);
```

Table to add rows to

```
        var gridFormat_2={
                    data : '',
                datatype : 'local',
                // mtype : 'POST',
                loadonce : true,
             viewrecords : true,
                   width : 600,                 
                  height : 500,                 
                  rowNum : 50,                  
                 rowList : [50,100,500],     
              rownumbers : false,               
             rownumWidth : 20,                  
                sortname : 'emp_no',           
               sortorder : 'asc',               
             multiselect : false,                
                sortable : false,              
               autowidth : true,                
                 iScroll : {zoom:true},          // cell mouse over시 Zoom
                   pager : '#jqGridPager_2',
                 caption : ' ',
              whitespace : 'nowrap', 
               wordbreak : true,
                 // autoRow : true,
               dragModel :{on: true, diHelper:['emp_no']},
               dropModel :{ on: true  },
              //colNames :['emp_no','emp_nm', 'pst_nm', 'dept_nm','dept_cd','pst_cd'],
                colModel :[
                                       {label: 'emp_no',            name:'emp_no',          index:'emp_no',         sortable:false, sorttype:'text',         width:50, align:'center',   editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'emp_nm',          name:'emp_nm',            index:'emp_nm',         sortable:false, sorttype:'text',         width:60, align:'center',   editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'pst_nm',            name:'pst_nm',          index:'pst_nm',         sortable:false, sorttype:'text',         width:60, align:'center', editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'dept_nm',           name:'dept_nm',         index:'dept_nm',        sortable:false, sorttype:'text',         width:60, align:'center', editable:false , height:'auto', cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;"' }}, 
                                       {label: 'dept_cd',       name:'dept_cd',         index:'dept_cd',        sortable:false, sorttype:'text',        width:130, align:'center',   editable:false , height:'auto', hidden:true }, 
                                       {label: 'pst_cd',        name:'pst_cd',          index:'pst_cd',         sortable:false, sorttype:'text',        width:60, align:'center',   editable:false , height:'auto', hidden:true }, 
                                       
                            ],   
            beforeSelectRow : function (rowid, e) {
                var $myGrid = $(this),
                i  = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest('td')[0]),
                cm = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                return (cm[i].name === 'cb');
            },
            loadError : function(xhr, status, err){ 
                try {
                    jQuery.jgrid.info_dialog(
                        jQuery.jgrid.errors.errcap,''
                        + xhr.responseText + '', jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose,
                        {buttonalign:'right'}
                    );
                } catch(e) { 
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                } 
            }
        };
         
        $.init_grid_table($("#main_table_2"),gridFormat_2);

        // Drag and drop

        $("#main_table_2").jqGrid('sortableRows',{
            update : function( e, html){ 
               console.log( html.item[0].id ); 
            }
        });
```

JS when event

```
$(document).on("click", "#main_table_1 tbody tr", function() {
    var rowIndex = $(this).index();
    var tr_cnt   = $("#main_table_1 tbody tr").length;
    // alert("rowIndex : "+rowIndex);
    // alert("tr_cnt : "+tr_cnt);
    // alert("addrowId : "+addrowId);

    for(var i=0; i<tr_cnt; i++){
        if ( i == rowIndex ) {
            $(this).parent().parent().find("tr").eq(i).find("td").css("background-color","#B0BED9");
                    
            
            AddrowSubtable(rowIndex);
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().parent().find("tr").eq(i).find("td").css("background-color","#fafafa");
            //alert("i: " + i);
        }  // if end
    }  // for end
});

function AddrowSubtable(rowIndex){
    var rowData = $("#main_table_1").getRowData(rowIndex+1);

    addrowId = $("#main_table_2").getGridParam("reccount");

    alert(JSON.stringify(rowData));

    
    $("#main_table_2").jqGrid('addRowData', addrowId+1 , rowData , 'last');

}
```

I'm asking you a question because I saw " [jqgrid addRowData gives error t.p.data.push is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856013/jqgrid-addrowdata-gives-error-t-p-data-push-is-not-a-function) "
but it didn't work.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? You maybe have the same error - check what is rowData in AddrowSubtable function? addRowData can accept array or object as parameters depending on the jqGrid version. I think you have bad value in rowData, the reason for this is that getRowData shuld have rowid as parameter, but not a rowIndex as you do. This is wrong. See docs please.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I find the cause of the error. The reason for the error is  "data : ''," of option.